# How to remove a single function from click event listener that has multiple functions, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, how do you remove a single function from a "click" event listener, after the first click event, when there are multiple functions being used on the element with the "click" event listener? Here, after the first click, only `toggleView()` should remain and `renderList()` should be removed.

```
const button = document.getElementById("view_button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleView(); // want to keep this indefinitely
  renderList(); // want to remove this after the first click
  button.removeEventListener("click", renderList);
});
```

Comment: Is adding 2 event listeners a choice or you need to handle both functions in the same listener? Adding 2 separate listeners would be a choice because you could remove the one calling `renderList` after executing once

Comment: From the code you posted, there's only **one** event handler, that anonymous arrow function. To get what you want, set a flag to keep track of whether a "click" has been handled, and use that to run or not run the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both separately, and specify `{ once: true }` on the one you want removed after first execution.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters):

> `once`
> A boolean value indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. **If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.**

```js
function toggleView() {
  console.log('toggleView');
}

function renderList(evt) {
  console.log('renderList');
}


const button = document.getElementById("view_button");
button.addEventListener("click", toggleView);
button.addEventListener("click", renderList, { once: true });
```

```html
<button type="button" id="view_button">Click</button>
```

Comment: For my own knowledge, what order are they executed in? The order in which the listeners are added?

Comment: Depending on whether you also have any delegate listeners, and also if you configred your listeners using `{ capture: true }` (which reverses bubbling into *trickling*). In general, first all listeners that are registered directly on the event emitter are called, in order of registration. Then those attached on the parent, also always in order of registration. This continues until you eventually reach `document` or `window`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two event listeners and remove the one

```js
function toggleView() {
  console.log('toggleView');
}

function renderList(evt) {
  evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener("click", renderList);
  console.log('renderList');
}


const button = document.getElementById("view_button");
button.addEventListener("click", toggleView);
button.addEventListener("click", renderList);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="view_button">Click</button>
```

or you can just add logic to determine if the function should be run.

```js
function toggleView() {
  console.log('toggleView');
}

function renderList() {
  console.log('renderList');
}


const button = document.getElementById("view_button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleView();
  if (!button.dataset.clicked) {
    renderList();
    button.dataset.clicked = '1';
  }
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="view_button">Click</button>
```

Comment: No need for manual removal here, check `once` optional parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters

Answer (score 0):

I would use a closure here to keep track of if the item has been clicked.

```js
const button = document.getElementById("view_button");

function toggleView() {
  console.log('Toggle View');
}

function renderList() {
  console.log('Render List');
}

function clickHandler() {
  let hasBeenClicked = false;
  return function () { 
      toggleView();
      if (!hasBeenClicked) {
        renderList();
        hasBeenClicked = true;
     }
  };  
}



button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler());
```

```html
<button id="view_button" type="button">View Button</button>
```

Comment: Again, for what OP needs the EventTarget API specifically already offers a solution.